# .htaccess - ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: .htaccess

Im using this .htaccess to add date,hour,minutes at end of my url example:

```
example.com/pagename?201502201855
```

It works in all my posts and pages but if i navigate to page number 2,3,4,5,6 example

```
example.com/page/2/?201502211929
```

then i get error: This webpage has a redirect loop Error code: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /


RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^(?!wp-admin)^(?!wp-login.php) %{REQUEST_URI}?%{TIME_YEAR}%{TIME_MON}%{TIME_DAY}%{TIME_HOUR}%{TIME_MIN} [L,R=302,NE]

RewriteCond %{TIME_YEAR}%{TIME_MON}##%{QUERY_STRING} ^([^#]+)##\1
RewriteCond %{TIME_YEAR}%{TIME_MON}%{TIME_DAY}%{TIME_HOUR}%{TIME_MIN}##%{QUERY_STRING} !^([^#]+)##\1
RewriteRule ^(?!wp-admin)^(?!wp-login.php) %{REQUEST_URI}?%{TIME_YEAR}%{TIME_MON}%{TIME_DAY}%{TIME_HOUR}%{TIME_MIN} [L,R=302,NE]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Is this part of WP .htaccess? Can you show full .htaccess in question?

Comment: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

HERE IS ABOVE CODE 

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

Comment: 1st rule is fine but what exactly are you doing in 2nd rule?

Answer (score 2):

In the `.htaccess` file, add the line:

```
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-Proto https HTTPS=on
```